# Change the Promise state of a Promise in Promise.all() when an asynchronous event occurs

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, async-await, promise, es6-promise

I'm using google Maps Api. I have two asynchronous events, the library API call and the position request for the user of the page. In the `geolocate() function` with `getCurrentPosition` I retrieve the coordinates of the user, this function return a Promises in a resolved state if all is ok, whit the position as `value`. To load the API library I'm using JSONP with a script dynamically added in `loadGoogleAPI()`, when the library is ready the callback function `googleAPILoaded` is called.  I have to continue the 'asynchronous execution' when the 2 above described asynchronous event occured and I'm using the pattern of the parallel execution in the `useGoogleMapsApi() function` (`await Promise.all`).
My problem is that when I call `Promise.all` , `Promise.all` for   the `googleAPIStatus` binds to the  its initial value `new Promise(()=>{})` pending Promise.  When the library with JSONP is loaded i change with `googleAPIStatus=Promise.resolve()` ,the value of the variable, to a resolved Promise but `Promise.all` instead remains related to the initial pending Promise value.
Here the code. How could I resolve?

```
 let googleAPIStatus = new Promise(()=>{});

  function googleAPILoaded(){
   console.log('loaded');
   googleAPIStatus = Promise.resolve(); 
}

  function useGoogleMapsApi(){
  loadGoogleAPI();//JSONP with a dynamic script
  let [_,posizione]= await Promise.all([googleAPIStatus , geolocate()]); //parallel execution pattern
  //Here if resolved either the Promises
  }

  function loadGoogleAPI(){
      let isLibraryLoaded = document.querySelector("script[src='google-api']"); 
      if(!(typeof google === 'object' && typeof google.maps === 'object')){
         //Add dynamic script that load the library
         let script = document.createElement('script');
         script.type='text/javascript';
         script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=HEREMYKEY&libraries=places&callback=googleAPILoaded';
         script.id  = 'google-api';
         if(!isLibraryLoaded)
            document.body.appendChild(script);
         else
            isLibraryLoaded.parentNode.replaceChild(script,isLibraryLoaded);
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can expose settles of `googleAPIStatus` `Promise` so you can settle it's state inside `googleAPILoaded` callback.

```js
let resolve, reject;
let googleAPIStatus = new Promise((_resolve, _reject) => {
  resolve = _resolve;
  reject = _reject;
});

function googleAPILoaded() {
  console.log('loaded');
  resolve()
}

setTimeout(googleAPILoaded, 100);

googleAPIStatus.then(() => console.log("resolved"))
```

Comment: Smart solution. It was exactly what I was looking for. I have already tested it on my code and it does the job. I don't understand who has downvoted my question. Furthemore I could not  insert a minimal executable code because the key API is not free.

Comment: @AnrDaemon `reject` is never used there, so no rejection can occure

Comment: Right you are. Sorry. Reject will simply throw unless caught.

Answer (score 1):

The other answer suggests exposing the resolver function, which is the *"deferred pattern"*, an anti-pattern to be avoided when possible because of its poor encapsulation.

Instead consider: ***"How would I write this if every API supported promises?"***

And then create that reality by wrapping every legacy non-promise API you encounter in Promise constructors ([which is their primary purpose](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises#creating_a_promise_around_an_old_callback_api)), or better, look for newer APIs.

In your case, a simpler way to wait for scripts to load already exists:

```js
async function loadGoogleAPI() {
  if (typeof google === 'object' && typeof google.maps === 'object') {
    return;
  }
  //Add dynamic script that load the library
  const script = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('script'));
  script.type = 'text/javascript';
  script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=HEREMYKEY&libraries=places';
  script.id = 'google-api';
  await new Promise(resolve => script.onload = resolve);
}
  
(async () => {
  try {
    await loadGoogleAPI();    
    console.log(typeof google.maps);
  } catch(e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
})();
```

Comment: `if (typeof google === 'object' && typeof google.maps === 'object') {
    return await Promise.resolve();
}` else you break your own contract.

Comment: @AnrDaemon Not necessary, as plain values returned in an `async` function automatically get wrapped in a Promise by the language.